# Can not extend django bootstrapped module

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

I am a django newbie and i can not extend `django_admin_bootstrapped.bootstrap3`, `django_admin_bootstrapped` modules. My Project Path looks like this:

[image]
also i use `{% extends "admin/base.html" %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
```

)

into settings.py

Answer (score 0):

1) Did u put django_admin_bootstrapped.bootstrap3, django_admin_bootstrapped **before** django.contrib.admin in this order?

> django_admin_bootstrapped.bootstrap3,
>
> django_admin_bootstrapped,
>
> django.contrib.admin,

2) Did u tried **./manage.py collectstatic** in shell?

Comment: my INSTALLED_APPS looks like this:

    'django_admin_bootstrapped.bootstrap3',
    'django_admin_bootstrapped',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',

also in TEMPLATE_DIRS `"C:/django-work/LST/static/templates",` works.

Comment: I did that it says 89 static files copied and nothing changed. I still can't make the changes appear.